# Does coil require extra resistor before connecting mains?

Tags: current, impedance, mains, coil

I am planning to build diaphragm air pump. For this instead of using an AC motor, I am planning to connect an aluminium rod to diaphragm, and put a permanent magnet on it that will be pulled and pushed continuously by the magnetic force of two coils.

These coils will be connected to grid (220VAC, 50Hz) in reverse direction. My expectation is that the rod will move back and forth continuously between two coils while the current changing direction, thereby the diaphragm will do pumping.

Since I do not have any this type practical experience with mains, I have a question to ask.

Since mains follow sine wave, when the current reaches to peak points, change
on current will be very small, and reactance of coils will be at its lowest,
and the impedance as well. Ignoring general impedance that is to be calculated based on frequency of mains, impedance of coils is expected to be changing based on delta t.

My question is that considering the above situation, should I be putting
a resistor before coils to prevent current getting too high due to low
impedance? As far as I see in electric DC motors, coils are directly connected.

---

Another related question is what I should do about flyback to prevent arcs? DC motors don't have anything on them and disconnected without a problem.

Comment: "These coils will be connected to grid (220VAC, 50Hz) *in reverse direction*" what does *in reverse direction* mean? What is "a cube iron"? You expect the rod to oscillate at 50Hz?

Comment: You are mixing time-domain properties (shape of sine wave) with frequency-domain properties (impedance of coil). Impedance is constant for a given frequency, regardless of instantaneous current.

Comment: @gbulmer By connecting reverse, while one coil is attracting the metal, other will be repelling, and vice versa.

Comment: @venny I know, I can calculate Z = XL + R, though thinking about the sine wave deeply, I assumed that would have effect.

Comment: Coil with AC current can attract iron, but not repel it.

Comment: @venny Actually yes, I thought about it later. Using a permanent magnet instead of iron block would be correct way to do it.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate (or measure) the inductance of your coils? Do you know how to calculate their impedance at 50 Hz from that? This is what will ultimately determine how much current flows. It'll be up to you to decide on the correct value. BTW, unless your moving "iron" is a permanent magnet, your coils will only attract, not repel.

Comment: It isn't 'a piston' in a sense I would understand. The word 'piston' is usually applied to an actuator which has a wider range of control than oscillating at 50Hz. Is that all you want it to do?

Comment: I want to build a diaphragm air pump. Something should push and pull the diaphragm continuously. Using a motor requires some mechanical work that I cannot do right now. So, I though using magnetic field and oscillating current, I could move the rod.

Comment: If you place two coils with opposite winding direction together, the magnetic flux will cancel out. In fact only one is needed.

Comment: Last time I fixed my ponds air pump it had two coils and a permanent magnet armature that oscillate to and fro between the antiphase coils. Well, that's what I summized.

Comment: @tcak - It would help us if you took the extra information that you have provided in your comments, add them to your question, and remove the things which are no longer relevant (like 'cube iron'). Then people reading your question have only one thing to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this scheme will not work because 50Hz/60Hz is too fast. You will just get a vibrating rod with very little travel. A better scheme might be to use a speaker and audio amplifier to drive it at a lower frequency. Remove the speaker cone, or direct connect to the driver coil where it connects to the cone. It is worth doing this because it is simple, safe and you can test whether the scheme is viable. What volume of air do you want to pump?

Comment: You are right about vibration. In 20mS, rod wouldn't be able to move much, and thereby lesser volume. Actually, before volume, pressure is important for me. 10-15 bar pressure would be required. I will fill a gas bottle.

Comment: There is another possibility, which is a magnetic linear actuator. It might be worth googling those terms because it is quite close to your original plan.